# C# linq SqlGeography - find locations within 50m by Latitude and Longitude

Tags: linq-to-entities, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I have lat and long in a SQL DB stored as 'float'

I'm trying the following where lat & lng are C# double

```
var yourLocation = SqlGeography.Point(lat, lng, 4326);
MyConn conn = new MyConn();
var query = from p in conn.Locations
           let distance = SqlGeography
            .Point(p.Latitude, p.Longitude, 4326)
            .STDistance(yourLocation)
            .Value
             where distance <= 50
select p;
return query.Distinct().ToList();
```

All I get is the following error

*LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble STDistance(Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

Any thoughts on this ??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/a77783e9-572e-4841-b4da-f2461296d596/).  I'm not aware of any corrections in EF4 but that doesn't mean they didn't correct it.

There is also an [article here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/04/spatial-types-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) regarding entity framework behaviour with spatial types.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to answer this question but for community help. This issue happens because **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types** is not  referenced in your project. just right click on reference and select add reference dialog box will appear select assemblies tab and search this assembly and select. Issue resolved.